# CloudFormation gives "Invalid template property or properties" error

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I get "Invalid template property or properties [TestLambda]" from the following cloudformation template.  I've validated the json with an online json validator.  I've tried removing the properties one by one, but still get the error.  The error message is useless in diagnosing the problem.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Thanks.

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "DeploymentBucket": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "S3 bucket name where built artifacts are deployed"
    },
    "ProjectVersion": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Project Version"
    },
    "DeploymentTime": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "It is a timestamp value which shows the deployment time. Used to rotate sources."
    },
    "DomainName": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Domain Name to serve the application"
    },
    "CloudSearchDomain": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Endpoint Name for CloudSearch domain"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "LambdaExecutionRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "Path": "/",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "lambda.amazonaws.com",
                  "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
        ]
      }
    },
    "LambdaCustomPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "LambdaCustomPolicy",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "s3:ListBuckets"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRole"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "TestLambda": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
    "Properties": {
      "Handler": "com.serverlessbook.lambda.test.Handler",
      "Runtime": "java8",
      "Timeout": "300",
      "MemorySize": "1024",
      "Description": "Test lambda",
      "Role": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "LambdaExecutionRole",
          "Arn"
        ]
      },
      "Code": {
        "S3Bucket": {
          "Ref": "DeploymentBucket"
        },
        "S3Key": {
          "Fn::Sub": "artifacts/lambda-test/${ProjectVersion}/${DeploymentTime}.jar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `TestLambda` resource is actually outside the `resources` JSON object. So, it failed the JSON validation at the AWS End with unexpected attributes.

Moving `TestLambda` inside `resources` will resolve the issue.

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "DeploymentBucket": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "S3 bucket name where built artifacts are deployed"
    },
    "ProjectVersion": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Project Version"
    },
    "DeploymentTime": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "It is a timestamp value which shows the deployment time. Used to rotate sources."
    },
    "DomainName": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Domain Name to serve the application"
    },
    "CloudSearchDomain": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "Endpoint Name for CloudSearch domain"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "LambdaExecutionRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "Path": "/",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "lambda.amazonaws.com",
                  "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
        ]
      }
    },
    "LambdaCustomPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "LambdaCustomPolicy",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "s3:ListBuckets"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "LambdaExecutionRole"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "TestLambda": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "com.serverlessbook.lambda.test.Handler",
        "Runtime": "java8",
        "Timeout": "300",
        "MemorySize": "1024",
        "Description": "Test lambda",
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "LambdaExecutionRole",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Ref": "DeploymentBucket"
          },
          "S3Key": {
            "Fn::Sub": "artifacts/lambda-test/${ProjectVersion}/${DeploymentTime}.jar"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was the problem.  I now get a different failure later in the deployment process. aws cloudformation validate-template is worthless.